# What is the default TCP window size on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, tcp, udp, settings

What is the TCP (and UDP) default window size on Windows Server 2008? I think it's 1480 bytes, but I'm not sure.

Can it be changed? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of Vista and Server 2008 is a next-generation TCP stack... it's auto-tuned, so there is no more TCPWindowSize tweak.

As far as changing it, you can turn auto-tuning on or off with these commands...

```
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=normal
netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disable
```

Answer (score 0):

Also note that the window size is not necessarily the same size as the MTU. It may be significantly larger - autotuning decides the best size for the network state.